# How to find records with unsuitable input value

Tags: sql, database, oracle, date

Running a query with most records filtered out using the where clause, I get a result.

But after removing the where clause I get the following error:

> ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month
>   01847. 00000 -  "day of month must be between 1 and last day of month

Now I want to know which records have unsuitable input values as I am using

```
nvl(to_date(trunc(vl.begin_date)),null) - nvl(to_date(trunc(v.end_date)),null) != 1
```

I searched for `null` records, but they don't seem to be the problem.

As the query itself is not the problem but rather finding the problematic records, I didn't add the complete query.

Comment: Can you provide sample data?  And data types?  I presume that dates are not stored as dates, because this error would be impossible.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, data is stored as timestamp. Can't include data, as I don't exactly know which records are the problematic ones.

Comment: @AlexPoole Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
"CORE 12.1.0.2.0 Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production

Comment: Calling `to_date()` on  a value that is already a date (or timestamp) is wrong. It first converts the timestamp to  a string just to convert that string back to a date which it was to begin with. Remove the `to_date()` calls from your statement.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, this seems to have helped to execute the query, but how do I find the records that have a problem?

Comment: @davejal - they *don't* have a problem; the unnecessary conversion is *creating* a problem that doesn't really exist. (Well, you could have invalid data in there but it's unlikely; it's much more likely to be related to your NLS settings. What is your session NLS_DATE_FORMAT set to, out of interest?)